# Two Selectboxes - load by selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I want, if I select a value in selectbox 1, that selectbox2 is loaded with values that are dependet on selectbox1.

Here´s how I tried:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#selectbox1").change(function(){
 var value = $(this).children('option.selected').val(); 
 $("#selectbox2").load("php/loadteams.php", {value: value} );

});
});

</script>
</head>


<body>

<?php 

include 'php/db.php';
$res = mysql_query("select * from liga", $connection);
echo '<select id="selectbox1">';
while($val = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$val['id'] .'">' . $val['name'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
mysql_close($connection);
?>



<select id="selectbox2"> </select>
```

Like you see, I tried with jquery. The file `loadteams.php` looks like that:

```
<?php
include 'php/db.php';
$ligaid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);

$result = mysql_query("select * from mannschaft where liga = '" . $ligaid . "'", $connection);

while($te = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<option> ' . $te . '</option>';  
}

?>
```

I don´t know where my mistake is - can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using the [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector, instead of `.selected` which would match a class with the name selected.

<strike>Also, I believe the `.load()` method posts data through HTTP GET, so I believe you would have to use `$_GET["value"]` instead of `$_POST['value']`.</strike>

**Correction:**

As you are providing the data as an object, it IS posted through HTTP POST, so strike my above statement. From the jQuery documentation:

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Comment: Actually in this case it uses `POST` since he passes some data to the request. From jQuery doc `The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.`

Comment: @spider Just realized that myself, corrected my answer. Thanks!

Comment: ok thanks. But the problem is still here. I added a value to selectbox2, now I know that the selected event is performed because when i select something in selectbox1 the value of selectbox2 dissapears

Comment: Check your Console/Network panel in Firebug/Developer Tools and to see what you are getting back from `loadteams.php`. Maybe no matches are found in your db so there's nothing to output, or there's some other error there

Comment: @user896692 What data does the the load-method return when you change the first select-box? You can use the developer tools in your browser to monitor the requests and check the response. Do you get a 200 OK from the server, is any data returned, is the data well formatted HTML?

Comment: Yeah, I get a 200 OK from the server! ... you can see my app here: http://hoerti.bplaced.net/insertbegegnung.php

Comment: @user896692 You get 200 OK, but the response is not what you think. Have a look at it in your web tools, or using Fiddler. Your server is throwing PHP-warnings.

Comment: @Christofer Eliasson How can I see PHP-warnings in Firefox? I just know the error console and there I can´t see any PHP-warnings

Comment: @user896692 You can see the errors by just browsing to http://hoerti.bplaced.net/php/loadteams.php

Comment: @user896692 Not sure how you check traffic in Firefox, using Chrome myself. Maybe you need Firebug for that.

Comment: Ok thanks, I solved it know. All the problem was just a wrong path! Thank you!

Comment: @user896692 Great, glad you found it!